# regular-expressions android

Tags: android, regex

i have string like these for example

309\306\308\337_338

309\306\337_338

310

311\315_316\336_337

311\315_316\336_337

311\335_336

these strings means list of page number , for example   string "309\306\308\337_339" means 
pages 309,306,308,337,338,339

i want to pass one of these string to function which return it as string like this 
309,306,308,337,338,339

this function do that but in c# , i want to impalement in android

```
 private static string Get_PageNumbers(string str)
    {
        ArrayList arrAll = new ArrayList();
        MatchCollection match;
        string[] excar;
        string strid, firstNumber, lastlNumber;
        int fn, ln;
        ArrayList arrID = new ArrayList();

        //***In Case The Range Number Between "_"
        if (str.Contains("_"))
        {
            // match_reg = new Regex("(w?[\\d]+)*(_[\\d]+)");
            Regex matchReg = new Regex("(w?[\\69]+_[\\d]+)*(q?[\\d]+//)*(a?[\\d]+_[\\d]+)*(y?[\\d]+)*");
            match = matchReg.Matches(str);

            int count = match.Count;
            excar = new string[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref excar, count);

                excar[i] = match[i].Groups[0].Value;
                if (excar[i] != string.Empty)
                    arrID.Add(excar[i]);
            }

            //******IF Array Contains Range Of Number Like"102_110"
            if (str.Contains("_"))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < arrID.Count; i++)
                {
                    strid = arrID[i].ToString();

                    if (arrID[i].ToString().Contains("_"))
                    {
                        int idy = strid.LastIndexOf("_");
                        firstNumber = strid.Substring(0, idy);

                        if (idy != -1)
                        {
                            lastlNumber = strid.Substring(idy + 1);
                            fn = int.Parse(firstNumber);
                            arrAll.Add(fn);
                            ln = int.Parse(lastlNumber);
                            for (int c = fn; c < ln; c++)
                            {

                                fn++;
                                arrAll.Add(fn);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arrAll.Add(arrID[i].ToString());
                    }
                }

                //******If Array Contain More Than One Number
                if (arrAll.Count > 0)
                {
                    str = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrAll.Count; i++)
                    {

                        if (str != string.Empty)
                            str = str + "," + arrAll[i];
                        else
                            str = arrAll[i].ToString();
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        //***If string Contains between "/" only without "_"

        else if (str.Contains("/") && !str.Contains("_"))
        {
            str = str.Replace("/", ",");
        }
        else if (str.Contains("\\"))
        {
            str = str.Replace("\\", ",");
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: And your questions is? Its not that hard to translate between C# and Java

Comment: @Morrison Chang aim beginner @ android i am trying but code crash and there are many exception

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is easier to do with `split` function:

```
public static String Get_PageNumbers(String str) {// Assume str = "309\\306\\308\\337_338"
    String result = "";
    String[] pages = str.split("\\\\"); // now we have pages = {"309","306","308","337_338"}
    for (int i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        String page = pages[i];
        int index = page.indexOf('_');
        if (index != -1) { // special case i.e. "337_338", index = 3
            int start = Integer.parseInt(page.substring(0, index)); // start = 337
            int end = Integer.parseInt(page.substring(index + 1)); // end = 338
            for (int j = start; j <= end; j++) {
                result += String.valueOf(j);
                if (j != end) { // don't add ',' after last one
                    result += ",";
                }
            }
        } else { // regular case i.e. "309","306","308"
            result += page;
        }
        if (i != (pages.length-1)) { // don't add ',' after last one
         result += ",";
        }
    }
    return result; // result = "309,306,308,337,338"
}
```

For example this function when called as follows:

```
String result1 = Get_PageNumbers("309\\306\\308\\337_338");
String result2 = Get_PageNumbers("311\\315_316\\336_337");
String result3 = Get_PageNumbers("310");
```

Returns:

```
309,306,308,337,338
311,315,316,336,337
310
```

Comment: Thank you Caner , but there are problem because string save at database with only one backslash "311\315_316\336_337" , when i try to s.replaceAll("\", "\\"); it dos't accept to apply because it read this "311\315_316\336_337" as "311Í_316Þ_337" , i also try to encode string and decode the result of encoding "311%C3%8D_316%C3%9E_337" but result of decoding still "311Í_316Þ_337" ????? How can i solve problem of one backslash ?????

Answer (score 0):

if i can suggest different implementation....

1. first, split string with "\" `str.split("\\");`, here you receive an array string with single number or a pattern like "num_num"
2. for all string founded, if string NOT contains "*" char, put string in another array (othArr named), than, you split again with "*" `str.split("_");`, now you have a 2 position array
3. convert that 2 strings in integer
4. now create a loot to min val form max val or two strings converted (and put it into othArr)
5. tranform othArr in a string separated with ","